# Open, closed, and compact sets in the product of two Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M_1, d_1)$ and $(M_2, d_2)$ be metric spaces.

Let $M = M_1 × M_2$ and define the distance function $d$ on $M$ by:

$d(x, y) = d_1(x_1, y_1) + d_2(x_2, y_2)$,
where $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$.

Suppose $A_1 ⊂ M_1$ and $A_2 ⊂ M_2$ and let $A = A_1 × A_2$.

(a) Prove that $A1$, $A2$ are both open if and only if $A$ is open.

(b) If $A_1$, $A_2$ are both closed, prove that $A$ is closed.

(c) If $A$ is compact prove that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are both compact.

So for (a), Assume $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open. Since $x_1 ∈ A_1$ and $x_2 ∈ A_2$, then there is an epsilon ball in each set centered around $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. I am not sure what to do after that. Am I allowed to say since $A = A_1 × A_2$, then the union of the epsilon balls are in $A$ and therefore it is open? 
I'm guessing for (b) I need to Sequential criterion of a closed set and for (c) I need to use open covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=(x_1,x_2)\in A$ there is a ball $B_{\epsilon_1}(x_1) \subset A_1$ and a ball $B_{\epsilon_2}(x_2) \subset A_2$. Now for $\epsilon < \min$ of the two epsilons, if $(z_1,z_2) \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ then $d_1(x_1,z_1) + d_2(x_2,z_2) < \epsilon$ so $d_1(x_1,z_1) < \epsilon < \epsilon_1$ and $d_2(x_2,z_2) < \epsilon < \epsilon_2$, so $z_1 \in B_{\epsilon_1}(x_1)$ and $z_2 \in B_{\epsilon_2}(x_2)$ thus $z_1 \in A_1$ and $z_2 \in A_2$, i.e. $z \in A$, therefore: $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset A$.

Other direction: suppose that $A$ is open. If $x_1 \in A_1$ then for a fixed $a_2 \in A_2$, $(x_1,a_2) \in A$ so there is $\epsilon$ such that $B_{\epsilon}((x_1,a_2)) \subset A$. If $z_1 \in B_{\epsilon}(x_1)$ then $d_2(x_1,z_1) < \epsilon$, so $d((x_1,a_2), (z_1,a_2)) = d_1(x_1,z_1) + d_2(a_2,a_2) = d_1(x_1,z_1) < \epsilon$, so $(z_1,a_2) \in A$ i.e. $z \in A_1$. Similarly for $A_2$.

If $x_n = (a_n,b_n) \subset A$ is a convergent sequence to $x =(a,b) \in M$ then $d((a_n,b_n), (a,b)) \to 0$ i.e. $d_1(a_n,a) + d_2(b_n,b) \to 0$, so it is easy to prove that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, so $a \in A_1$ and $b\in A_2$, i.e. $x\in A$.

If $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $A_1$, then $(O_i \times M_2)_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $A$, so it has a finite subcover $(O_i \times M_2)_{i=1}^m$, and $(O_i)_{i=1}^m$ is a finite subcover of $(O_i)_{i\in I}$. Similarly for $A_2$.